# Subclass of UIView, can't set it's own layer.cornerRadius?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have subclassed UIVIew to make my custom view.

```
-(UIMyMessageView*)init:(NSString*)withMessage
 {
   [super initWithFrame:messageFrame];

   // I Would like to do : 
   self->layer.cornerRadius = 8; // This doesn't compile
 }
```

Why can't I set my own layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

include QuartzCore Framework

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Also include this framework in your project.

http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/03/xcode-4-adding-a-framework-to-your-project/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```